# Calculate best fit line based on points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have been struggling with a math issue. I am in need to find the best starting and ending point for a straight line so that it intersects most of the circles (the blue one always needs to be intersected).

As you can see in the image below I want to be able to calculate that green line based on the given points, where the blue one is required to be intersected.

I've tried to apply the best fit algorithm but that doesn't really takes intersection in consideration. Would appreciate if someone could help me out solving the math for this.

There will only ba a maximum of **5** circles while calculating the best line to take.

**Note: I am not deeply involved into math, only know the basic symbols for it.**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this problem using linear least squares. Let $P = (x_P, y_P)$ be the point that the line must intersect. Since you know the line intersects point $P$, you only need to solve for the slope of the line going through the point $P$ that minimizes the residual.

To do this, you can shift all the points, so that $P$ is at the origin and solve $mx = y$ to obtain the slope, $m$. Now, you can solve the linear system $\textbf{A}m=\textbf{b}$ where

$$\textbf{A} = \begin{bmatrix} x_1-x_P\\ x_2-x_P\\.\\.\\.\\x_n-x_P \end{bmatrix}$$

and

$$\textbf{b}= \begin{bmatrix} y_1-y_P\\ y_2-y_P\\.\\.\\.\\y_n-y_P \end{bmatrix}$$

then, solve using the normal equation, $m = (\textbf{A}^T\textbf{A})^{-1}\textbf{A}^T\textbf{b}$. Keep in mind the points were shifted while solving $\textbf{A}m=\textbf{b}$, so the final equation for the line will be $y=m(x-x_A) + y_A$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying to implement it in the programming language C#. As I understand to calculate "A", I have to iterate over all the points and sum the result of "xn−xP", correct? So I end up for a scalar value for each A and B. Now to calculate "m" I see you included the variable "T", what does this stand for if I may ask?

Comment: Ah I see it is for transposing a matrix, so that is cleared up. I think my math skills are too lacking for me in order to fully understand what everything stands for and how to properly calculate the examples you gave me.

Comment: Yes. $\textbf{A}$ and $\textbf{b}$ are both matrices of size $n \times 1$  where superscript $T$ stands for transpose and $(x_P, y_P)$ is the point your line intersects and $(x_1,y_1), ..., (x_n,y_n)$ are your other points. You can simply plug in those values and solve for $m$, then your equation will be $y=m(x-x_A) + y_A$. As far as understanding why the math works, you will want to read about the least squares method.

Comment: Also, if you need to program this, there are several linear algebra libraries that can do the matrix multiplication and inverse for you. If you are worried about efficiency even though you only have 5 points, there are libraries that implement efficient solvers using SVD, QR factorization, or LU decomposition for equations of the form Ax=b, which is how I formulated it. If you need help with implementing these solvers, I recommend posting another question on another stack exchange site about the solvers specifically. Good luck!